# What kind of code can I have in a Neo4J unmanaged extension?

Tags: database, neo4j, architecture, graph-databases

Is it a good idea to put any kind of logic in Neo4J unmanaged extensions?

As an example:

- Integrations
- Large CPU/memeory intensive calculations
- Data access
- Upload of files

What are the pros/cons for having an architecture with another runtime handling those kind of things?

How good is Neo4J on scaling tasks like this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a tendency to move to [procedures](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.0/#procedures) now, instead of unmanaged extensions, but the question still stands in that context.

You can have a look at the [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) project for an already large number of things done Neo4j-side.

In addition to those examples, you'll run any type of [graph traversal](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorial-traversal) in Neo4j as well, especially for stuff too complex to express through Cypher queries: the traversal framework allows you to split the computation into smaller, more manageable parts (`PathExpanders` and `Evaluators`). To use it, you have no choice but to put the logic in the extension, where it can run close to the data.